# Eclipse wont recognise google play services as a project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

So I'm trying to add Google Play services to my project as a library but I cant seem to import it to my Eclipse. It doesn't seem to recognize it as a project. When checking what is different between this and other projects it seems like the Google play services doesn't have a .project file.

I think this is why I cant import it but is it meant to have that even though its only a library and why didn't the Android SDK download the .project when getting it?

Comment: How are you trying to import it?

Comment: using the eclipse to import it. File>import>Existing projects into workspace

Comment: File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace should not expect a `.project` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have specified the path incorrectly i.e. you have drilled down too far in the directory hierarchy.

The correct path is Android ...android-sdk...extras...google...google_play_services

(From that level in the hierarchy you will see the assets, bin, gen, libs ... folders and of course the .project file.)